# http get request malformed or invalid request

Tags: mysql, google-cloud-functions, postman, httprequest

I've got a simple GET request running on Firebase Functions to connect to an AWS SQL server. I've also written POST, PATCH, and DELETE Functionalities and they work just fine, but for some reason when I try running my GET request I constantly keep getting a 400 malformed or invalid request error. Here is the request

```
exports.getPosts = functions.https.onRequest(async(data,context) => {
    //checkAuth(context);
    const followingQuery = await db.collection('users').doc('uRPCxsfZDnWoCnvhUSInlUFkQVf2').collection('followed-livestreams').get();
    let usersFollowing = [];
    for(let i = 0; i < followingQuery.docs.length; i++) {
        usersFollowing.push(followingQuery.docs[i].id);
    }
    const options = {
        method: 'GET',
        json: true,
        uri: 'URL FOR HANDLING REQUEST',
        body: {
            "followingList": usersFollowing,
            "sortByPopularity": true,
        },
    };
    try {
        const body = await rp(options);
        console.log(body);
    } catch(e) {
        console.log(e);
        throw e;
    }
});
```

I've tried with and without json:true, and with and without
`header: {'Content-type': 'application/json;charset=utf-8'},`
The code for the GET request might also be useful, so that is here

```
post.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "URL YOU ARE MAKING THE REQUESTS FROM");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods","GET, POST, DELETE, PATCH");
    res.header('Content-type', 'application/json;charset=utf-8')
    var data = req.body;
    console.log(data);
    var dataRecieved = JSON.parse(data);
    console.log(dataRecieved);
    var sqlStr = "select * from News_Feed.Posts;";
    var followerListSql;
    if(dataRecieved.followingList.length > 0) {
        for(let i = 0; i < dataRecieved.followingList.length; i++) {
            followerListSql.add("'" + dataRecieved.followingList[i] + "'");
        }
    }
    if(dataRecieved.sortByPopularity == true) {
        sqlStr = "SELECT * from News_Feed.Posts WHERE posterId IN (' " + followerListSql + "') ORDER BY reactionPoints DESC;"
    } else {
        sqlStr = "SELECT * from News_Feed.Posts WHERE posterId IN (' " + followerListSql + "') ORDER BY posted DESC;"
    }
    _conn.query( sqlStr , (err, result, fields) => {
    if (err) throw err;
    var finalResult = [];
    for (var item of result) {
        finalResult.push({
            "id": item.id,
            "posterId": item.posterId,
            "posterName": item.posterName,
            "posterPicture": item.posterPicture,
            "posted": item.posted,
            "type": item.type,
            "url": item.url,
            "text": item.text,
            "reactionPoints": item.reactionPoints,
            "fiveCount": item.fiveCount,
            "commentCount": item.commentCount,
        });
    }
    console.log(finalResult);
    res.json(finalResult);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is that HTTP Post doesn't allow a request Body